# Beautiful Soup Multiple Answers from Single Question

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an html quiz that has multiple answers with Beautiful Soup. I am able to scrape answers and questions independently and have kind of figured out how to combine some of them, **ERROR** below. The issue is that some questions have more than one answer, so I am off by one on the output i.e. question 1 with multiple answers will only have one then question 2 will have question 1 answer. There are a lot of layers in the html code i.e. checkboxes, correct tags and incorrect tags answers... this repeats itself in the same order for the next question. End state is to scrape the correct questions and answers then dump them into a flash card program for studying purposes. I am not sure if this is the best approach or if there is another python library that would work better? Any direction and help would be greatly appreciated.

## Question 1 HTML:

```html
<div class="detailed-result-panel--panel-row--2aE8z detailed-result-panel--question-container--7NyiS">
   <form class="">
    <div class="mc-quiz-question--header--3fsHJ">
     <span>
      Question 1:
     </span>
     <span class="mc-quiz-question--incorrect--1QOBY">
      Incorrect
     </span>
     <div class="mc-quiz-question--question-prompt--2_dlz" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html" id="question-prompt">
      <p>
       Select TWO examples of XYZ.
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <ul aria-labelledby="question-prompt" role="group">
     <li>
      <div class="mc-quiz-answer--answer-body--1JtTQ mc-quiz-answer--incorrect--2v11K checkbox boxed disabled">
       <label title="">
        <div class="pos-r">
         <input checked="" data-index="0" disabled="" name="answer" type="checkbox"/>
         <span class="toggle-control-label checkbox-label">
 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fx toggle-control-label">
         <div class="fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--incorrect--2v11K">
          <div class="fx">
           <div class="mc-quiz-answer--question-copy--314BC" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html">
            <p>
             ANSWER 1
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mc-quiz-answer--correctness--3pFQG">
           (Incorrect)
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </label>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="mc-quiz-answer--answer-body--1JtTQ checkbox boxed disabled">
       <label title="">
        <div class="pos-r">
         <input data-index="1" disabled="" name="answer" type="checkbox"/>
         <span class="toggle-control-label checkbox-label">          ​
         </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fx toggle-control-label">
         <div class="fx fx-lc">
          <div class="fx">
           <div class="mc-quiz-answer--question-copy--314BC" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html">
            <p>
             ANSWER 2
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </label>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="mc-quiz-answer--answer-body--1JtTQ mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db checkbox boxed disabled">
       <label title="">
        <div class="pos-r">
         <input checked="" data-index="2" disabled="" name="answer" type="checkbox"/>
         <span class="toggle-control-label checkbox-label">          ​
         </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fx toggle-control-label">
         <div class="fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db">
          <div class="fx">
           <div class="mc-quiz-answer--question-copy--314BC" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html">
            <p>
             ANSWER 3
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mc-quiz-answer--correctness--3pFQG">
           (Correct)
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </label>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="mc-quiz-answer--answer-body--1JtTQ mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db checkbox boxed disabled">
       <label title="">
        <div class="pos-r">
         <input data-index="3" disabled="" name="answer" type="checkbox"/>
         <span class="toggle-control-label checkbox-label">          ​
         </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fx toggle-control-label">
         <div class="fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db">
          <div class="fx">
           <div class="mc-quiz-answer--question-copy--314BC" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html">
            <p>
             XYZ Management
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mc-quiz-answer--correctness--3pFQG">
           (Correct)
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </label>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="mc-quiz-answer--answer-body--1JtTQ checkbox boxed disabled">
       <label title="">
        <div class="pos-r">
         <input data-index="4" disabled="" name="answer" type="checkbox"/>
         <span class="toggle-control-label checkbox-label">          
         </span>
        </div>
        <div class="fx toggle-control-label">
         <div class="fx fx-lc">
          <div class="fx">
           <div class="mc-quiz-answer--question-copy--314BC" data-purpose="safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html">
            <p>
             ANSWER 4 
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </label>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

## Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('inputfile.html', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

questions = soup.find_all('div','mc-quiz-question--question-prompt--2_dlz')

answers = soup.find_all('div','fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db', 'safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html')

for q, a in zip(questions, answers):
    print(' '.join((q.p.text, a.p.text)))
```

## My Output:

```
Select TWO examples of XYZ. ANSWER 3 
What does XYZ provide? ANSWER 4 <--- this is from the previous Question
```

## Expected Output:

```
Question: Select TWO examples of XYZ. 
Answer: ANSWER 3 ANSWER 4 
Question: What does XYZ provide? 
Answer: ANSWER 1
Question: How does XYZ do ABC? 
Answer: ANSWER 3
```

## Error

This will parse through about halfway then error, assuming it is expecting a text type and returning something else.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myparsar.py", line 111, in <module>
    print(' '.join((q.p.text, a.p.text)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand correctly you want to scrape multiple corrected answers from a single question. You did it mostly correctly. But in the for loop you're using the zip function wrongly. I recommend you checking it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

If you have multiple questions you should start finding all by its container:

```
question_containers = soup.find_all('div', 'detailed-result-panel--question-container--7NyiS')
```

Then you can iterate through every container to get the question and answers.

```
for container in question_containers:
    question = container.find('div', 'mc-quiz-question--question-prompt--2_dlz')
    answers = container.find_all('div', 'fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db', 'safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html')
```

As you have more than one answer for a question you should use nested for loops to iterate through all them:

```
ans = []
for a in answers:
    answer_text = a.text.strip().split('\n')
    ans.append(answer_text[0])
print('Question:\n', question.text.strip(), '\nAnswers:\n', ', '.join(ans))
```

For each answer I use .text, .strip and .split to get only the answer text. Then I append it to a list of answers and I use this list to print out what you want.

### Ful code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

question_containers = soup.find_all('div', 'detailed-result-panel--question-container--7NyiS')
for container in question_containers:
    question = container.find('div', 'mc-quiz-question--question-prompt--2_dlz')
    answers = container.find_all('div', 'fx fx-lc mc-quiz-answer--correct--is6Db', 'safely-set-inner-html:rich-text-viewer:html')

    ans = []
    for a in answers:
        answer_text = a.text.strip().split('\n')
        ans.append(answer_text[0])
    print('Question:\n', question.text.strip(), '\nAnswers:\n', ', '.join(ans))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes this is what I am trying to accomplish. I think I see a better path, but the code is actually populating all the answers.  

#OUTPUT:
' Question:
 Select TWO examples of XYZ.
Answers:
 ANSWER 3, ANSWER 4, ANSWER 3
Question:
 What is an example of XYZ.
Answers:
 ANSWER 3, ANSWER 4, ANSWER 3'

Comment: Thats because you getting every answer in a single find. I would suggest you to first find all question container. And then in each container you look for the question and correct answers. I'll edit the answer to match your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for the most part. For some reason in the larger data set it was grabbing `(Correct)`, so I added a replace to remove it and was also playing around with a return instead of a newline `answer_text = a.text.strip().replace('(Correct)','').split('\r')`  I tried to filter with  BeautifulSoup to remove it, but wasn't successful. I can now grab the text and write out to anki flashcards. 